# How can I debug an encrypted package in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

As the package will be encrypted, I cannot see the actual code. So, I cannot debug the code. Is there any way to debug an encrypted package, while I don't have the decrypted version of it?

Comment: The code is not "encrypted", You can simply revert with https://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/

Comment: if it's your code, you should have the raw source for it in your source code repo, yes? debug it from there. If it's someone else's code and they've WRAPPED it, then you won't be able to debug it